Why does jenkins readyaml stop working after you create a StringJoiner?
I created the following script
import groovy.json.*

pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'mycomputer' } }
    stages {
        stage ( 'Test') {
            steps{
                script {
                    StringJoiner a = new StringJoiner(",");
                    a.add("a").add("b").add("c")
                    env.out = a.toString()
                    echo env.out
                    datas = readYaml file: "/home/cloud-user/test.yaml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This results in this output:

[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
a,b,c
[Pipeline] readYaml
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@7bb36fb8
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@636cffca
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@2664c301
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@1339b8f9
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@146a9a96
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@146a9a96
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 16a49acb-27b5-4869-b5ae-bfdb1ca5e058
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.StringJoiner
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:278)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:341)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1858)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1412)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:134)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:231)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1128)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:341)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1858)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1412)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:134)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:231)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1128)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:116)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$1(RiverWriter.java:144)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:331)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:580)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:557)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:540)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:464)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:97)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE

Removing the readyaml command causes the error to disappear. This doesn't make any sense to me, why would it try to serialize the StringJoiner in the unrelated readyaml call?
Yaml contents
---
HELLO: "WORLD"


See documentation:

Local variables are captured as part of the pipeline’s state during serialization. This means that storing non-serializable objects in variables during pipeline execution will result in a NotSerializableException to be thrown.

readYaml and most other steps (but not all) triggers serialization. I guess it is a fundamental trade off - Jenkins pipeline execution can survive Jenkins restart, but to do that it asks you to only have serializable variables, so it can save and restore its state after the restart.
Doesn't mean you cannot use any non-serializable classes, because you can, just don't save their instances to variables. This is no problem:
env.out = new StringJoiner(",")
  .add("a").add("b").add("c")
  .toString()



An alternative to Iterokun's answer is to create a function and annotate that with @NonCPS. This will tell Jenkins to omit the results from serialization. However, unless I misinterpreted my recent experiences, you then cannot access any pipeline specific functions or fields like readYaml or env.
If I recall correctly, you don't need to import NonCPS in pipelines, but if you want to, the fully qualified class is com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS.
For example:
import groovy.json.*

pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'mycomputer' } }
    stages {
        stage ( 'Test') {
            steps{
                script {
                    env.out = joinValues()
                    echo env.out
                    datas = readYaml file: "/home/cloud-user/test.yaml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def joinValues() {
    StringJoiner a = new StringJoiner(",");
    a.add("a").add("b").add("c")
    return a.toString()
}


Good point! And you are allowed to use env and some steps, like echo, in @NonCPS function. But all the functions you call from a @NonCPS function must also be @NonCPS.
